# How do i URL rewrite an image properly? C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mime, url-rewriting

I tried several ways to URL rewrite. The first way the image mime was clobbered and was consider an octet stream which didnt allow me to view the image in a browser (unless it was using img src). The 2nd way i wasnt convince it worked. Firefox displayed the img but said the length was 0 (i think it only worked bc it was in my cache).

How do i properly rewrite the image /abc/id/title.png to the internal location /static/user/name/id.png

Comment: @Daniel A. White: I am not sure. i call my C# code via global.asax. I dont know what Webforms or MVC are.

Comment: Could you post the code/config that shows how you're currently trying to do the URL rewriting?

Comment: Webforms is a standard asp.net web application.  If it were ASP.NET MVC this would mean that you went to ASP.NET and downloaded the MVC framework (unless you are on a very new SP or using VS10?).  They are separate templates when selecting what type of website to create.  Do your urls says {domain}/webpage.ASPX or do they say {domain}/webpage ??

Comment: You are just repeating the same question over and over. You should show your progress so far, otherwise you will only get the same answers over and over.

Comment: Andrew Siemer: msvs9/2008. It says localhost:port/default.aspx Its sounds like i am using webforms but all i have is default.aspx to print some debug info, lazy.aspx which i rewrite to and handle the request from and global.asax which rewrites the paths i use to lazy.aspx. I am not actually using any forms or anything. Its all C# code inside my DLL

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET I might do something like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = profile.AvatarMimeType;
Response.BinaryWrite(profile.Avatar.ToArray());
```

Where profile.AvatarMimeType is an appropriate mime type for a gif, jpeg, or png.

And where profile.Avatar.ToArray() is a binary content from the db sent out as an array of data!

Comment: I have not tried this in ASP.NET MVC but I think that it should still work as the URL simply gets you to the resource that executes this code.